# Replacing text between n-th and (n+1)-th delimiter using sed

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I wonder how I can change a single value on particular position in pipe delimited dataset.

For example, I have data set:

```
01|456|AAAA|James Bond|AAAA|207085
02|AAAA|BBBB|Marco Polo|BBBB|937311723
03|321332|BBBB|Brad Pitt|AAAA|6296903
04|3213|AAAA|AAAA|BBBB|62969
```

I want to change every "AAAA" value to "XXXX", but only between 4th and 5th pipe character ( | ). So, expected output will look like:

```
01|456|AAAA|James Bond|XXXX|207085
02|AAAA|BBBB|Marco Polo|BBBB|937311723
03|321332|BBBB|Brad Pitt|XXXX|6296903
04|3213|AAAA|AAAA|BBBB|62969
```

Is it achievable using only `sed` function, or is it necessary to use something like `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set input field separator (`FS`), output field separator (`OFS`) and if column 5 contains `AAAA` replace by `XXXX`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $5=="AAAA" {$5="XXXX"}1' file
```

Output:

```
01|456|AAAA|James Bond|XXXX|207085
02|AAAA|BBBB|Marco Polo|BBBB|937311723
03|321332|BBBB|Brad Pitt|XXXX|6296903
04|3213|AAAA|AAAA|BBBB|62969
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `awk` for this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {gsub(/A/, "X", $5)} 1' file

01|456|AAAA|James Bond|XXXX|207085
02|AAAA|BBBB|Marco Polo|BBBB|937311723
03|321332|BBBB|Brad Pitt|XXXX|6296903
04|3213|AAAA|AAAA|BBBB|62969
```

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}` uses pipe as a input & output field separators
- `gsub(/A/, "X", $5)` replaces each `A` with `X` in `$5` for 5th column only
- `1` is default action to print each line

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v start=4 -v end=5 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{for(i=start;i<=end;i++) gsub(/AAAA/,"XXXX",$i)}1' inputfile
01|456|AAAA|James Bond|XXXX|207085
02|AAAA|BBBB|Marco Polo|BBBB|937311723
03|321332|BBBB|Brad Pitt|XXXX|6296903
04|3213|AAAA|XXXX|BBBB|62969
```

Based on the value of `start` and `end` variable, `gensub` function will do the replacement between the columns falling between these values.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/^(([^|]*\|){4}X*)[^X|]/\1X/;ta' file
```

Iterate, replacing all characters that are not an `X` or a `|` to an `X` from the fourth `|` character.